# In a typical document where does sans font apply?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I am learning about the `fontspec` package to load fonts when compiling with Xelatex. I am aware of three types of fonts - **mainfont** which applies to the main text in paragraphs, **monofont** which applies to `verbatim` and other code blocks and **sansfont** - which I dont know anything about. In a typical document where does sansfont apply ? The math ? Is is possible to use `fontspec`'s `\set...font{}` commands to set the math font separately ? or is it the same as that of the mainfont ?

**Edit**: I should mention that the main reason I ask this question is because I have used the font `Garamond-Math.otf` which came with my TeXLive distribution as my **mainfont** (`\setmainfont{Garamond-Math.otf}`) and am very pleased with the look. However I am not sure if using a font which has "Math" in the name as the main document font is a good idea or if its considered bad practice ?

Comment: To define an Opentype math font, one has to load the `unicode-math` package (which, incidentally, loads the `fontspec` package automatically) and execute `\setmathfont`, with a syntax that's similar to `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont`, and `\setmonofont`.

Comment: You need to specify what *you* think a "typical document" is.

Comment: it's an artistic choice, it's like saying "typically when should I wear blue?"  there is no answer. On this site for example all text is sans serif.

Comment: but the math font is designed for math, texlive has GaramondLibre-Regular.otf for text (along with bold and italic variants

Comment: As far as I remember, `beamer` might use sans by default. Sans is said to be better for screen use, and serif for paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fontspec` doesn't really set fonts for a specific purpose or environments like `verbatim`. So, for example, `\setmonofont` does not tell LaTeX "use this font for code blocks" but rather says something like "use this font when asked to switch to `\ttfamily`" (which happens for codeblocks).

Similarly, `\setsansfont` sets the font to be used when switching to `\sffamily`, which can be invoked for different things, depending on your documentclass and own presets. For example, KOMA-classes use this font for headings etc. (basically anything that's bold in standard classes), or you could use it in your own commands, e.g. if you want all your emphases to be `\sffamily\bfseries`.